# Compare two arrays and add or replace content?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an object **A** and **B**. object **B** is to be compared to **A**. New content from **B** should be added to **A**. If the keys at **A** and **B** are the same, the contents of **B** are to be replaced in **A**.

In short:
**A** is my default object and object **B** should overwrite content or add it to object **A** again.

The right approach would be to search for duplicate entries and delete them. Then object B is simply added completely to A. Is that correct? How can I do that?

**Object A looks like this:**

```
{
  "slidesPerView": 3,
  "direction": "vertical",
  "roundLengths": true,
  "keyboard": {
    "enabled": true,
    "onlyInViewport": true
  },
  "breakpoints": {
    576: {
      "direction": "horizontal",
      "slidesPerView": "auto"
    }
  }
}
```

**Object B looks like this:**

```
{
  "slidesPerView": "auto",
  "direction": "horizontal",
  "roundLengths": false,
  "breakpoints": {
    576: {
      "direction": "vertical",
      "slidesPerView": 5
    }
  }
}
```

**The result would be the following:**

```
{
  "slidesPerView": "auto",
  "direction": "horizontal",
  "roundLengths": false,
  "keyboard": {
    "enabled": true,
    "onlyInViewport": true
  },
  "breakpoints": {
    576: {
      "direction": "vertical",
      "slidesPerView": 5
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to search for duplicate keys. You can iterate through `objectB` directly, and add each of it's keys to `objectA`

```
for (var key in objectB) {
  objectA[key] = objectB[key]; // If key exists in objectA, it will be overwritten with the value from objectB. If it doesn't, it will be created (with the value from objectB)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(objectA)); // This should output the result you were looking for
```

Comment: It does not work that way. Nested objects are completely overwritten. Existing options should be kept if only one option is changed.

Comment: Oh, I see. How deep can the nested objects get?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. There can be up to 3 nested objects.

Comment: Perhaps you could then do something recursive.